# configuring transform-inline-environment-variables for react-native 0.60.6

Tags: react-native, plugins, babeljs

```
module.exports = function () {
  return {
    "presets": ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    "plugins": [
      ["transform-inline-environment-variables", {
        "include": [
          "APP_ENV"
        ]
      }]
    ]
  }
};
```

This is my babel.config.js for my react-native project, and I'm trying to configure the transform-inline-environment-variables babel plugin. But whenever I run the app the environment variable is always undefined.

I run `react-native start --reset-cache` to clear the cache and run the project using the command `APP_ENV=dev react-native run-ios`.

But the variable is still undefined. What am I doing wrong here? The react-native version is 0.60.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try logging access directly (rather than destructuring):

```
console.log(process.env.APP_ENV)
```

Also, once you have the emulator connected, you can *then* run `start`, so:

1. `yarn run-ios`
2. Close the metro bundler terminal window and leave the emulator open
3. `API_ENV=dev yarn start --reset-cache`

This issue is covered in detail [here](https://github.com/babel/minify/issues/687).

Better still, replace your implementation with [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config).